# QUnit, Sinon.js - How do I ensure Post to Fake Server has correct request body?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, sinon

I have a JavaScript function that does a Post to a remote API that I am looking at writing a unit test for. The method I want to test is this:

```
var functionToTest = function(callback, fail) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/myapi/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { one: 'one', two: 'two' },
        accept: "application/json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function(x) {
        log = generateLogMessage('Success');
        callback(log);
    }).fail(function(x, s, e) {
        log = generateLogMessage('Fail');
        fail(log);
    });
}
```

I have a unit test (in QUnit leveraging Sinon.js) that tests that the callback is called correctly when the request succeeds:

```
QUnit.test('Test that the thing works', function () {

    var server = this.sandbox.useFakeServer();

    server.respondWith(
        'POST',
        '/myapi/',
        [
            200,
            {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            '{"Success":true}'
        ]
    );

    var callback = this.spy();
    functionToTest(callback, callback);
    server.respond();

    QUnit.ok(callback.calledWith(generateLogMessage('Success')));
});
```

This test works, but it returns successfully regardless of what the request body. What I want to do is only have the Fake Server respond if the request body is `{ one: 'one', two: 'two' }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to suggest that you use [filtered requests](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#filtered-requests). However this is not possible with the current implementation of sinon.

excerpt from documentation:

> Add a filter that will decide whether or not to fake a request. The
>   filter will be called when xhr.open is called, with the exact same
>   arguments (**method, url, async, username, password**). If the filter
>   returns truthy, the request will not be faked.

You don't have ability to filter on the data.

EDIT: If I understand the problem correctly, you might be able to do something like this:

```
functionToTest(...);
var request = server.requests[0];
var data = JSON.parse(request.requestBody);
if (data.one == 'one' && data.two == 'two') {
  request.respond(200, jsonHeaders, JSON.stringify(specialResponse));
}
else {
  request.respond(200, jsonHeaders, JSON.stringify(otherResponse));
}
```

I know that code will get the correct result that you want, but there's not a way to programmatically accomplish that with sinon right now.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will keep doing what I am doing then.

Answer (score 13):

Almost two years later now, but still relevant:

This can be achieved by passing a **function** instead of an array as the third parameter to `server.respondWith`. The function takes one argument 'request', on which you can call `request.respond(statusCode, headers, body);`

You'll still have to extract the values from `request.requestBody`, but at least it's doable.

```
QUnit.test('Test that the thing works', function () {

    var server = this.sandbox.useFakeServer();

    server.respondWith(
        'POST',
        '/myapi/',
        function (request) {
            console.log(request.requestBody); // <- assert here :-)
            request.respond(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, '{"Success":true}');
        }
    );

    var callback = this.spy();
    functionToTest(callback, callback);
    server.respond();

    QUnit.ok(callback.calledWith(generateLogMessage('Success')));
});
```

Comment: The code for xhr.respond: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/fd56d7f0c2c749e21475a630bee99ffdbc090516/lib/sinon/util/fake_xdomain_request.js#L150

Comment: This should be the real answer now